# Run Application from Service, CreateProcessAsUser Fails

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-services

I know! I shouldn't run a GUI application from a Windows service, but this is what I should accomplish as a requirement. Putting different codes from around the Web together, I have the following procedure. I see Access Violation error in log, as a result of CreateProcessAsUser. I have tries different settings with no luck. Any idea what is wrong with this code?

```
procedure TMyService.RunApp;
var
  SessionID: DWORD;
  UserToken: THandle;
  CmdLine: PChar;
  si: _STARTUPINFOW;
  pi: _PROCESS_INFORMATION;
begin
  SessionId:= WtsGetActiveConsoleSessionID;
  if SessionID = $FFFFFFFF then Exit;
  if WTSQueryUserToken(SessionID, UserToken) then begin
    CmdLine:= 'notepad.exe';
    ZeroMemory(@si, SizeOf(si));
    si.cb := SizeOf(si);
    SI.lpDesktop := PChar('winsta0\Default');
    SI.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    SI.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    ZeroMemory(@pi, SizeOf(pi));
    try
      CreateProcessAsUser(UserToken, nil, CmdLine, nil, nil, False,
      0, nil, nil, si, pi);
    except on E: Exception do
      // Log exception ...
    end;
    CloseHandle(UserToken);
  end else begin
    // Log GetLastError ...
  end;
end;
```

BTW, WTSQueryUserToken is used from JEDI API Library and is defined as:

```
function WTSQueryUserToken(SessionId: ULONG; var phToken: THandle): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Comment: What's the exact Access Violation message? Do you know which line it fails on? Have you tried this procedure outside of the service, so that you can debug? For the record, it's perfectly okay for a service to launch an app on a user's desktop, a lot of software works this way. It's just the service itself cannot interact with the desktop.

Comment: @JerryDodge, It is "Access violation at address 766BA61D in module 'KERNELBASE.dll'. Write of address 005E6312". FYI, a service can not simply run `ShellExecute` to run a GUI app. Because they are in different sessions and that's why I'm using this approach.

Comment: It's those addresses I'm asking about, they do actually mean something.

Comment: I edited the comment with correct address.

Comment: @JerryDodge, And as I mentioned in the question, it fails on CreateProcessAsUser line.

Comment: Thanks for including that. It tells me that there is likely some sort of type mis-match. What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: @JerryDodge, interesting. How could you tell the reason (type mis-match) form addresses?

Comment: An address such as `00000000` would mean something that's not instantiated at all yet (nil). If you get an access violation with any other address, it means something is trying to access memory, but that memory block contains data which doesn't match the desired data. It could also mean an address which was once instantiated properly, but has since been released (and thus recycled for different data).

Comment: It's not a type mismatch. That's a compile error. Access violations are quite different, being run time errors. I'm not sure why @Jerry said that, but he was wide of the mark.

Comment: The point is that knowing the address of an A/V helps you know what to look for. That was also before knowing what the real issue was, as explained in the answer.

Comment: @Jerry You said type mismatch though

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, before the answer below was posted. I was just suspicion ("likely").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third parameter must be a pointer to a modifiable string, as documented on MSDN:

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessAsUserW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

A string literal is stored in read only memory.  Try this instead:

```
var
  CmdLine: string;
....
CmdLine := 'notepad.exe';
UniqueString(CmdLine); // make modifiable;
....
if not CreateProcessAsUser(..., PChar(CmdLine), ...) then
  // handle error
```

Comment: Wow. I read "If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation" on MSDN, but I thought a string variable is enough. I didn't know about `UniqueString`. Works perfect.